# Hide all redirect informations

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I'm using Response.Redirect to serve media files, but don't want people to see the direct url to the files nor the subdomain (host). Is it possible to fake a 'get', and hide host and referer?

Comment: You would have to do basically a form of a "server side redirect". This basically means you download it on your server, and then the client downloads it from your server. Unless you have a very good reason to do this, it's very inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to transfer the request processing to another page.

> When you use the Transfer method, the state information for all the
>   built-in objects are included in the transfer. This means that any
>   variables or objects that have been assigned a value in session or
>   application scope are maintained. In addition, all of the current
>   contents for the Request collections are available to the .asp file
>   that is receiving the transfer.
>
> Server.Transfer acts as an efficient replacement for the
>   Response.Redirect method. Response.Redirect specifies to the browser
>   to request a different page. Because a redirect forces a new page
>   request, the browser makes two requests to the Web server, so the Web
>   server handles an extra request. IIS 5.0 introduced a new function,
>   Server.Transfer, which transfers execution to a different ASP page on
>   the server. This avoids the extra request, resulting in better overall
>   system performance, as well as a better user experience.

Since the browser doesn't make another request, the url is totally hidden from the browser, but it still gets the file that will be served by your redirect url.

Comment: That perfectly made the job for files on my webserver. 0 information are shown when redirecting.

Comment: This along with the method I found to redirect stream makes both internal and external link obsfucated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339322/response-redirect-a-download-in-progress/12362804

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible - for a simple reason: To have the client download the file **directly** from another source, you need to communicate the information about the location to the  client in some way: If the client doesn't know the location, it can't download from there.

Whatever you try in the way of obfuscation, if it is decodable for the client browser, it is decodable for a human being armed with firebug.

Comment: Very true. What I finally made for external links is to redirect a stream by downloading the external file with a buffer and writing the buffer to the response while it's downloading.